# MCBrowserViewController not found

Tags: uitableview, ios7, multipeer-connectivity

I'm unable to use the MCBrowserViewController class, as described from the presentation from WWDC 13. I don't know where I'm going wrong -- I added the multipeer connectivity kit framework, and included the header file. No syntax highlighting pops up from Xcode for MCBrowserViewController, although the other ones (MCSession, etc.) work fine. Is this just because I am using a beta version of XCode 5 and haven't updated to the final one yet, or is there a bigger issue here?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember `MCBrowserViewController` didn't get added to the Multipeer Connectivity framework until DP2 or DP3 of Xcode 5. The simple answer here though is to download the current production version (5.0.2) - it's definitely in there.